# C# NET 3.5 : Property or indexer cannot be assigned to “--” it is read only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, collectionview

I have a readonly property:

```
public CollectionView View { get; }
```

and I am trying to initialize it from the class constructor:

```
public MyClass()
{
   this.View = ......
}
```

But the error described in the title is appearing. I am using NET 3.5 on Visual Studio 2008. I remember that in later versions of .NET and Visual Studio a readonly property could be initialized/assigned only from the constructor. Is it not possible in .NET 3.5? If not, how can I do this in .NET 3.5? I mean, I want a readonly property and only be assigned once in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# 3.0 they didn't add special handling for read-only autoproperties so you must do it the old way:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly CollectionView _View;
    public CollectionView View { get { return _View; } }

    public MyClass() {
        this._View = ...;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax should be:

```
public CollectionView View { get; private set; }
```

Comment: The problem with that is a private setter doesn't prevent non-constructor methods from changing the property value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly backing field and a property with only getter. Like this

```
readonly CollectionView _view;

public CollectionView View { get {return _view;} }

public MyClass()
{
    _view = ....
}
```